# How do I execute a MongoDB4.2 js script using the Spring data Mongodb or Java MongoDriver

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am updating mongodb 3.4 to mongodb 4.2

In the mongoDB 4.2 the eval command no longer exists

Before I could execute the following with mongodb 3.4

```
String script = "db.firstColl.find({'_id':'573fcafd-584d-447c-a762-53567283b2b0'}).forEach(function(x) { var fact = x.data.fact; print(fact);});"      
ScriptOperations scriptOps = mongoTemplate.scriptOps();
ExecutableMongoScript echoScript = new ExecutableMongoScript(script);
return scriptOps.execute(echoScript);
```

Is there any other way for this code using mongodb4.2 and Spring data Mongodb.

Please help me

Comment: Instead of print, you should get it into a list and then print it using `System.out.println();`

Comment: The problem is not so much the print. The problem is that it can no longer run mongo scripts

Comment: Please check the below answer for better explains, how to execute the custom queries. Hope that will resolve your problem.

Comment: I have verified this in the MongoDB version `4.0.14`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `spring-data-mongodb` features `@Query` annotation in the Mongo Repository to write the Mongo shell query and execute it as it is, as below:

**e.g:**

```
@Query("{'organization' : ?0, 'active' : true, 'fields' : {$elemMatch : {'key' : ?1, 'value' : {$regex : ?2, $options: 'i'}}}}")
List<Springdata> findFieldDataByRegexMatch(String org, String key, String pattern);

@Query("{'organization' : ?0, 'active' : true, 'fields' : {$elemMatch : {'key' : ?1, 'value' : {$regex : ?2, $options:'si'}}}}")
List<Springdata> getDataByQueryAnnotation(String org, String key, String pattern);
```

The above one is just for examples and after getting the data from this query you can do whatever you want.

Another way to do this is that write the two classes one for Query preparator from JSON and another for executor as below:

**Query Preparator class**

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

public class CustomFindPreparator extends Query {

  private String jsonOperation;

  public CustomFindPreparator(String jsonOperation) {
    this.jsonOperation = jsonOperation;
  }
}
```

**Query executor class**

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import sample.data.mongo.models.Course;

@Service
public class CustomFindQueryExecutor {
  @Autowired
  private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  public void RunCustomQuery() {
    String query2 = "{\"name\" : \"mathematics\"}";

    List<Course> courseList = (List<Course>) mongoTemplate.find(new CustomFindPreparator(query2), Course.class, "course");

    System.out.println(courseList);
  }
}
```

In the String `String query2` you can pass any query from Mongo shell and then execute it in spring-data-mongodb.

For more details about the implementation, you can visit my Github page: [Link](https://github.com/krishnaiitd/learningJava/tree/master/spring-boot-sample-data-mongodb/src/main/java/sample/data/mongo/services)
Mainly you have to check the classes **CustomFindPreparator** and **CustomFindQueryExecutor** only.

Comment: This is not so bad because and answer the use case in the question. But it is not the same. With the previous exemple, you could execute query from an external file *.js.
With your solution, you would need to parse the file and you would probably need to not write native query in it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I could find is the following

```
public Object nativeQuery(String query) {
    CommandResult commandResult =  mongoTemplate.executeCommand(query);
    Map cursor = (Map)commandResult.get("cursor");
    return cursor.get("firstBatch");
```

}

```
public Object responseQuery(){
     StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("{                         ");
     query.append("find: 'impCollection',                                      ");
     query.append("filter: { 'data.est':'ACEPTADA','data.ver':0},       ");
     query.append("projection: { 'data.docSop': 1, 'security': 1},      ");
     query.append("sort: { 'security.fecCre': 1 },                      ");
     query.append("limit: 5                                             ");
     query.append("}                                                    ");

     return nativeQuery(query.toString());

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The eval command has been removed without replacement in MongoDB Server 4.2.0.

Read further at [Spring-Mongo documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/ScriptOperations.html) or [Mongo's official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.eval/#db.eval).